# Cannot use imported library in newly defined function

Tags: python, ipython

```
In [27]: import math

In [28]: math.log
Out[28]: <function math.log>

In [29]: sum(math.log(v) for v in range(10))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
[...].py in <module>
----> 1 sum(math.log(v) for v in range(10))
[...].py in <genexpr>(.0)
----> 1 sum(math.log(v) for v in range(10))

NameError: name 'math' is not defined
```

I'm completely confused. Why does this not work.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your bug, can you give more information about your system environment ?

> The problem does not come from there, but you must use `range(1, 10)` instead of just 10, because log is not defined for 0.

Here is what I have.

```py
Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import math
>>> math.log
<built-in function log>
>>> sum(math.log(v) for v in range(1, 10))
12.80182748008147
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce it either. What I can reproduce is if I define a function before `import math` which uses `math.log` and it then of course fails when I call it, and then call `import math` and redefine the function, I still get an error `math is not defined` afterwards